# Strategy for Incremental Datasource fetchings in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, database, odbc

I am in an scenario with a table that is refresh by a third app every week.
I need to keep accumulating all data in Excel, using an ODBC connection to the database.

I am wondering

**Approach 1:** Is there a way to force Excel to **append** results for every update (this update would be triggered according to a parameter that indicates week)? I tried to define the table for which the connection loads using a dynamic reference but once is anchored first time, table position is never redefined

**Approach 2**: Use an ETL to accumulate all weekly results into a staging table and then connect Excel to it in real time. But, I would need a mechanism for caching old data, as I cannot grow exponentially the time Excel opens. Imagine after 10 years, Excel would need to update at opening 10 years fo data before showing it. Is there a way to store already fetched data and increment it at real time (when book is opened) by selecting new data (with a query/filter of something)

Thanks

EDIT: Maybe it's better to ask it that way: What is the optimal strategy for a table that keeps growing and needs to be read in real time by Excel? I just don't want to fetch absolutely all data after some months...

Comment: Yes, this is going to be an issue if I've understood correctly. What does happen to 'old' data. EG, if you were to delete the content, would ALL the content from all time re-appear on next refresh? If so, are you connecting the via the DATA tab in Excel? If so, you could easily restrict the data by date or ID or similar (depends on what you have access to in the query)? If you can restrict the amount of data like this, then approach 1 would work

Comment: Old data is always deleted in every refresh by my Third App. So if I manage the approach 1 (ideal), it would be captured in Excel and then unlinked from the connection so I keep in Excel all-time data. I am now connecting via Data tab and ODBC. I can restrict the data changing the query but I need to tell Excel to append at every update instead of refresh/overwrite.

Comment: Oh I see, and are you now asking how to keep the old data then? If that is the case you can write a little macro which runs after the third party app does its thing. It will literally copy the content into Worksheet2. Since this is your code, you can control if you want to append it or not. Is that what you're after?

Comment: My third app is leaving data in a volatile table. Is there a way to do it backwards, excel fetching and appending to current results from the table (aside from using an Excel's very macro)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I only know the way I describe. Let the 3rd party app do it's thing, creating new data on (eg) Sheet1. Then, after this, your app copies this data from Sheet1 and appends it to the top of the table on Sheet2 (your historic data)

Comment: Oops. Sorry. When I refer to table I mean SQL table stored in a db.

Comment: Well yes, if you have view rights to the table, then you can query the table and do what you like with it.. But this has made your question more complicated as I thought the data was done via a third party

Comment: Sorr, English is not my mother tongue. My problem is querying it incrmeentally, so it appends the content instead of refreshing a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for Excel to tackle this.  It can handle appending results from a SQL query to an existing table.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/append-queries-HA104149760.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA103993872

If you store the data in the Excel Data Model format (not in an Excel Table), the data is highly compressed - there are reports of people storing 160 million rows in this format (with 64-bit Excel).  You can then access the data back into Excel via Pivot Tables and/or Cube Formulas.

Answer (score 0):

I found the selected answer a bit lacking (but a great start :)

Using the latest PowerQuery (starting from Nov2014, you can load to the workbook in addition to loading to the data model)

Here, the **Source** data is just a table in Excel but you can pull from anywhere including a SQL DB.

Step one.  Create an initial load.  The Query is named FROM (The name is inherited from the table name: FROM)

```
let
    //Load from Table FROM
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="FROM"]}[Content],
    AddCustom = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Load Date", each DateTimeZone.UtcNow())
in
    AddCustom
```

Load to the data model AND to the worksheet.  The worksheet table is called **FROM_2** by default.

Update the FROM query like so:

```
let
    //Load from Table FROM
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="FROM"]}[Content],
    AddCustom = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Load Date", each DateTimeZone.UtcNow()),
    //Load from Table FROM_2  (this is just a copy of what's in the DataModel)
    Custom1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="FROM_2"]}[Content],
    ChangedType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Custom1 ,{{"Load Date", type datetimezone}}),
    //Append the two Loads.  The New data and the existing loads in the DataModel
    Append = Table.Combine({ChangedType,AddCustom})
in
    Append
```

So, now you can just, for example, add a Pivot table pointing to the DataModel or to the FROM_2 table.
If you need another table with the data in the DataModel where you can add other colums you can just create another Query pointing to the FROM_2 table.

Since you're using a table in the worksheet as an intermediate step, I doubt this will scale for a lot of data.